# CodeLite static library does not find include file

Tags: c, macos, static-libraries, file-not-found, codelite

I've created a simple project to learn how to create a static library. I've created a new workspace in CodeLite and a new project and a new static library.

In the static library I've got, inside a "include" folder a .h file called `helloworld.h` and inside a "src" folder a .c file called `helloworld.c`. The output files are generated in a folder inside the workspace in a folder called lib (../lib).

Inside the same workspace I have a project with a file .c where the helloworld is called with `#include "helloworld.h"`. Finally, the settings of the project are:

linker menu:

[image: linker menu]
          Libraries search path: ../lib 
          Libraries:

[image: HelloWorldLib]

General Menu:

[image: general menu]

When I compile the project I got the following error:

```
      fatal error: 'helloworld.h' file not found
```

The only way that the project compiles without problems is to get the relative path to the file within the include parameter:

```
       #include "../HelloWorldLib/include/helloworld.h"
```

I wonder if there is a way to work without having to add the path to the file.  I'm using CodeLite in MAC OS 10.9.5. The same problem occurs in Ubuntu.

My teacher explained that this does not occur in CodeLite Windows, but he doesn't know what could be happening in Mac. Moreover, it should not be necessary to use the path within the include parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the "Compiler" tab instead of the "Linker" tab, try adding your 'include' directory under the "Include Paths" option.